# External Link Button Under Post Excerpt on Index.php

Tags: customization, excerpt

I'm starting a reviews website and at the moment I have, as standard, my post excerpts on the main index page.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way in which I can add a link (preferably a button) at the bottom of each post excerpt on the index page in which the viewer can go straight to the site I'm reviewing, without reading the post?

I'd like the post heading to go to my article, but a button at the bottom to go to said website that's being reviews, saying something along the lines of "Go to Site"

For example:

- Site 1 Name: Review
- Post excerpt here...read more
- External Link to site 1 (as a button).
- Site 2 Name: Review
- Post excerpt here...read more
- External Link to site 2 (as a button).

If it can be done by plugin, then I'm OK with that. I'm also OK with editing the code of my site should that be the only way to achieve this.

Theme is Codilight-lite if this helps in any way, shape or form.

If anyone can help, that would be amazing.

Many thanks

Comment: Add a custom meta box so you're adding the external URL directly in the post editor as postmeta. Then you can filter the_excerpt to include that postmeta as a link.

Comment: I like this answer. After a few occurrences of the white screen of death, I've added a custom meta box in the Edit Post area and added the code to save the meta date. However, please could you advise how to filter the_excerpt?

Comment: You may get an actual answer outlining what @WebElaine has suggested, it's the technique many WP developers would use if they are comfortable with building their own plugins and themes (I'm too lazy right now to do it myself). You'll probably find it much easier to use Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) though. It will allow you to add a field to any post where you can fill in the URL for the site you are reviewing, and then use a small bit of php to output that field in your template.

Comment: `add_filter( 'the_excerpt', function ( $excerpt ) { return $excerpt . " more stuff for the excerpt." } );`

Comment: Thanks! Took me a while to figure out exactly where to add the additional code, but I found it eventually. I've added plain text at the moment, but will have a look at adding it in as a button. I'll report back!

Comment: @totels - I've hit a bit of a wall with this. I found the excerpt settings in a file called extras.php. The general set up is slightly different to the above example you provided (as all the excerpt code is passed as several $variables. I was able to add custom text at the end of the excerpt, but wasn't able to add an html style button. Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on your theme, you might need to remove the built-in filter and then add your own in a child theme. (Even if you do it another way, if you're editing the parent theme you need to instead create a child theme and revert parent theme changes.) http://brianjohnsondesign.com/how-to-remove-filters-using-child-theme/

Answer (score 1):

The Codilight theme is bypassing the usual `the_excerpt` with their own version:

`inc/extras.php +26`:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'codilight_lite_excerpt' ) ) :
  /**
   * Get the except content limit by characters.
   *
   * @param string $characters
   * @return string
   */
  function codilight_lite_excerpt( $characters ){
    // $characters = 160;
    $excerpt = get_the_content();
    $excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $characters);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
    $excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
    $excerpt = $excerpt.'...';
    return '<div class="ft-excerpt">'. $excerpt .'</div>';
  }
endif;
```

And on top of that they aren't even using "proper" methods of modifying via actions or filters to make it easy for child themes. Instead they've wrapped their function with a clause to check whether you've written your own, which allows you to override theirs. So in your `functions.php` you'll need to basically copy their function and add your own code as needed.

add to
`your-child-theme/functions.php`:

```
  /**
   * override the parent theme excerpt
   *
   * @param string $characters
   * @return string
   */
  function codilight_lite_excerpt( $characters ){
    $excerpt = get_the_content();
    $excerpt = preg_replace( " (\[.*?\])", '', $excerpt );
    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $excerpt );
    $excerpt = strip_tags( $excerpt );
    $excerpt = substr( $excerpt, 0, $characters );
    $excerpt = substr( $excerpt, 0, strripos( $excerpt, " " ) );
    $excerpt = trim( preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt ) );
    $excerpt = $excerpt . '...';
    $excerpt .= "<br><button>Visit Site</button>";
    return '<div class="ft-excerpt">' . $excerpt . '</div>';
  }
```

Fetching the metadata and building the actual button code I will leave upto you.